# Using hook as a callback function

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm familiar with the [Rules of Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html), with the *reason* for the rules (ensuring that hooks are always called in the same order), and with the `eslint` warning.

In some cases, when the callback function itself is a hook instead of an arrow function,  the `eslint` warning goes away. See **Example** code below.

### Example

Here's some code, with a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/hooks-as-callbacks-5gm9r?file=/src/App.js). (Warning: Contrived and do-nothing code ahead).

```js
import React from "react";

export default function App() {
  const list = ["a", "b", "c"];

  // The call to useSomething() could be made in ListItem,
  // and it would certainly be cleaner.
  // However, it is made here intentionally,
  // to demonstrate that there is no eslint
  // warning and no error from React when the callback
  // for map() is declared as a custom hook.

  const transformed = list.map(function useCb(val) {
    return useSomething(val);
  });

  return (
    <>
      <h2>
        Hook as <code>Array.map()</code> callback
      </h2>

      <ul>
        {transformed.map((val, i) => {
          return <ListItem key={i} val={val} />;
        })}
      </ul>
    </>
  );
}

/**
 * Trivial example of custom hook with reusable state logic,
 * for demonstration purposes.
 * A real hook would be more complex and do something sensible.
 */
function useSomething(val) {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState(null);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    // Do something with `val`.
    // Store result in state.
    setState(`result of \`useEffect()\` on \`${val}\``);
  }, [val]);

  return React.useMemo(() => `Expensive tranformation to ${state}`, [state]);
}

function ListItem({ val }) {
  return <li>{val}</li>;
}
```

The Rules state:

> Don’t call Hooks inside loops, conditions, or nested functions. Instead, always use Hooks at the top level of your React function, before any early returns.

Assuming that "top level" means top of the call stack, not nested:

I would say that in this case, the call to `useCb()` is *not* at the top level of the React function because it is nested in `Array.map()`, and is also in a loop. I consider `Array.map()` to be a loop.

So, I would say that this implementation violates the Rules of Hooks.

The standard `eslint` warning reads:

> React Hook "<hook_name>" cannot be called inside a callback. React Hooks must be called in a React function component or a custom React Hook function. (react-hooks/rules-of-hooks)

To me this implies mutual exclusion, as in: "If it's in a React function component or custom React Hook function, then it's not inside a callback and therefore is OK."

But in this case, I would say that the `useSomething()` hook is called inside the callback `useCb()`, which is *also* a custom React Hook function.

I can see why this may be a risky, "bad idea". If `list` is dynamic, then the number of hook calls may change.

But if it violates the Rules of Hooks and is otherwise a risky bad idea, why is there no linting warning or React error about incorrect hook usage?

Is this just a case of omissions in the error checking and / or ambiguity in the verbiage? Or is it a legitimate implementation for rare edge cases where the order and number of hook calls *does not change*? Or something else?

Comment: I suppose it only "bends" the rules, and doesn't outright break them, though, if the length of the array changes ever you'll see one of the other React hook errors about the order of hooks changing between renders.

Comment: @DrewReese Exactly. If `list` is dynamic, it may introduce problems that the Rules of Hooks are meant to prevent. So, it's probably a risky, bad idea in most cases. And that's the gist of my question... There are no linting warnings or React errors. Does that mean it's "OK" as a general rule, or does that mean that the error-checking is deficient?

Comment: Well, lint warnings come out of static code analysis, React errors come from runtime exceptions. They are sort of Apples and Oranges.

Comment: I understand. But either may occur in cases like this. If I were to use this pattern in a `useEffect` callback, React would display an error in dev mode, with the standard error popup that obscures the page. And React in `StrictMode` displays errors when it detects a difference in the number or order of hooks. The point I'm making is that neither the linting plugin nor React's built-in error checking have a problem with this implementation.

Comment: How would you use this pattern in a `useEffect` hook? Can you clarify that comment?

Comment: ```useEffect(function useCb() {
  useSomething(val)
}, [val])
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238075/discussion-between-kentr-and-drew-reese).

Comment: Hmm... The "continue this discussion in chat" link was created by s.o., when I acted on the email which s.o. sent me suggesting that. I didn't realize that the link doesn't actually work.

Comment: The room was deleted, but did you still have something further to discuss?

Comment: Thanks for asking. I didn't have anything further at this point. I am not familiar with that feature, and I was more concerned that anyone trying to join the discussion would not be able to because the link doesn't work.

Comment: Ah, I see. The link should still work (*at least the one from the comment thread above*), but no new conversation can be had. Cheers.